# Using the Ag plugin, how to not automatically open the first result?

Tags: plugin-ag.vim

Looked through the options through `:help Ag` but didn't see anything. The closest I got was `lhandler` but that's only controlling the new window that opens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was right there, if you append a `!` to the command, it'll not open the first result. I'll map `:Ag` to `:Ag!`.

```
:Ag[!] [options] {pattern} [{directory}]                               *:Ag*

    Search recursively in {directory} (which defaults to the current
    directory) for the {pattern}.  Behaves just like the |:grep| command, but
    will open the |Quickfix| window for you. If [!] is not given the first
    error is jumped to.
```